# Families of graphs for which MAXCUT values is known?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, discrete-optimization

The max-cut (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cut) is NP-hard in general. However can we enumerate the families of graphs for which the value is known explicitly? For example a bipartite graph's max-cut would be trivial.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want *this* particular question answered.  Most (all?) sophisticated graph theoretic software will return *max* (or *min*) cuts for an input graph.  Of course for very large graphs this may be beyond available computational resources.

Comment: @david - This is more a theory question rather than a computational one. The fundamental issue being, maxcut is NP-hard.

Comment: OK.  Given that this is a *theory* question, what does a list of graphs and max cuts reveal (in your mind)?  Why do this at all?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I guess thats a personal preference as to what constitutes an interesting question :) To me, it is interesting to understand when does the Goemans-Williamson SDP have an optimal solution which is also rank-1 (which corresponds to the exact value of the MAXCUT). I would have expected more literature on this given how well studied these are but unfortunately I don't find much.

Answer (score 1):

I would comment, but I cannot yet.

I suggest you this [website](https://www.graphclasses.org/), which is basically a database of all graph classes important enough to be even defined.

Specially, you can see their complexity towards the $MAXCUT$ problem listed [here](https://www.graphclasses.org/classes/problem_Maximum_cut.html).

Comment: This looks like an answer to me!